# CSS breaks on reload mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not very skilled at CSS. I have website that has 4 stylesheets and 3 JS files-using Bootstrap 4 and jQuery. When I deployed it on live and refresh the page, all was working fine.

However, when I go to website from mobile, it works fine the first time but when I refresh, all the CSS and HTML is broken (this usually happens after 1st or 2nd refresh). After it is broken, I refresh it once or twice, it fixes the issue. I searched about it and some say it is happening because of using relative positioning and floating, but when I commented out those lines from my CSS files, I still have the same problem. Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this issue?

index html

**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Landor App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
<style></style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/fonts.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/intro.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/home.css" type="text/css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/video.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/modals.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
<!--INTRO PAGE-->
<div id="intro-page" class="container-fluid" style="display: none">
    <div class="row intro-header">
        <div class="col-12"><img id="landor-worldmark"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row intro-text">
            <div class="intro-text col-12">
                <h3>Hi Andrew,</h3><br>
                <h3>We can't wait to welcome you to Landor London.
                 Until then please take a few minutes
                 <span style="white-space: nowrap;">(3, to be exact)to explore more about us...</span></h3><br>
                <h3>Regards,</h3>
                <h3>Peter</h3><br><br>
                <span id="enter-button">Enter</span>        
            </div>          
    </div> 
    <div class="intro-footer row">
            <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid intro-boat"></img></div>
    </div>      
</div>
intro.css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.intro-text{
   font-family: "apercuBold"; 
}
#intro-page{
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
body {
  background-color:black;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.intro-text{
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}
#enter-button{
  font-family: "timeposRegular"; 
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 150%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
}
.intro-header{
  padding-top: 3%;
}
.intro-text{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#landor-worldmark{
  content:url("../assets/Landor_Logo.png");
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
}
.intro-boat{
  content:url("../assets/boat2.png");
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  float:right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .intro-text > h3{
     font-size: 100%;
  }
  .intro-text{
      font-size: 100%;
      line-height: 1.4;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  #enter-button{
     font-size: 100%;
  }
  .intro-boat{
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    float:right;
  }
  .intro-header{
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  .intro-text > h4{
     font-size: 90%;
  }
  .intro-text{
      font-size: 94%;
      line-height: 1.1;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  #enter-button{
     font-size: 94%;
  }
  .intro-boat{
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;

  }
  .intro-header{
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
}
.intro-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: here is the link as you refresh on mobile you will see that css changes: http://stagingwalterawards.landorsystems.com/LandorApp/index.html

Comment: Part of that was _minimal_. Please create the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem and include it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled out my phone and went to the site, and used the Browser tools phone emulator option (i don't know if that's what it's called) and it looks just fine on reload. Maybe try restarting your phone or clearing cache.

Is it because you are tilting your phone and switching the view from horizontal and vertical (That still shouldn't change anything)

Comment: Thank for you that. However, if you refresh it  one or two times you will see that the content and boat image sticks to the right most on that yellow page. It has padding from both left and right sides. However, when you refresh, the right padding disappears and they all move to right most of the page

Comment: Nope. Do you want me to record it? There is absolutely nothing changing for me... Have you restarted your phone and cleared cache?

Comment: Someone who is testing it had the same problem. We both are using IOS. When I rferesh the page, as I mentioned above, we experience the same issue on the first or second refresh. I restarted phone but it didin't help. The interesting thing is when I copy that link and open up in another tab. I dont have any issue. The issue is only happening on refresh. are you using ios device? (This issue is happening on both chrome and safari on ios). Sure if you could record, that will be very helpful. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I am on an Iphone 5s

Comment: same here. Im not sure why you dont have the issue

Comment: I did still no luck... I mean the page doesn't break when copy and paste same url on a new tab, but it breaks if I refresh the page once or twice. Still trying to figure out what is causing this

Comment: intresting..., I still can't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

After a whole day, I finally solved this problem by adding "?" at the end of my stylesheets paths on the link tag. It's a caching issue, although I disabled caching, for some reason it did not work. Now I refreshed the page > 10 times and never experienced any problem! I think, because of the question mark, when it is loading the CSS, first it's checking to see if there is another version available which prevents it from fetching from the cache completely.